# Cant upgrade to windows 11 due to virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

Ok, so I came across this error when trying to upgrade to Windows 11. It used to be 2 of the same errors, but it said I had to uninstall VirtualBox, and I did. So now it's just one error and its this one:

[image: Error]

At first, I thought it was related to Docker, so I uninstalled Docker desktop and re-tried the installation. And I still got the same error!

I don't even know where it gets the installer gets the VirtualBox issue from as there is no Virtualbox installed on my machine anymore.
So can anybody help me?

### possible causes

- Docker? I already mentioned that I uninstalled it and re-tried the installation yet got the same error

Comment: Find and run WhyNotWin11 from GitHub.  See if there is another reason why you cannot upgrade. Is your machine new in the last 30 months?.  Also you might try Windows 10 Repair Install and use Keep only Data.  That removes your software but keeps Data and your Windows Profile.

Comment: [Windows 11 has a couple documented issues that block it’s installation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-21h2#1704msgdesc). You really should wait until the issue is resolved. Try removing Hyper-V

Comment: Articles on this subject indicate it can several days for your device to be offered Windows 11.  If you really want to skip that wait you should be able to use the Windows 11 Media Creation Tool